# Regex for special characters inside brackets

Tags: java, regex

I've the below string, Now I want to match the string if it contains `Continue? [Y/N]`. I tried couple of ways but it didn't worked as expected. Any suggestions to match the complete string if contains `Continue? [Y/N]`

**Input String:**

```
Warning: do you want to proceed, some-more,text. Continue? [Y/N]
```

Comment: I tried like this, ".*Continue(\?\s)?\[Y\/N\]*"

Comment: `[` and `]` need to be escaped if you want to match them literally. Try preceding your brackets with `\\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
(?=^.*Continue\? \[Y\/N]$)(^.*Continue\? \[Y\/N]$)
```

The first group is a positive look ahead checking whether `Continue? [Y/N]` exists at the end of the line or not, if it exists the second group matches the whole string , you can see test cases at link given below.
Note: the special characters has to be escaped to match it literally, `[` , `?` and `/`. since you are using java you need also to escape, `\` .

```
(?=^.*Continue\\? \\[Y\\/N]$)(^.*Continue\\? \\[Y\\/N]$)
```

[See text at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pnd5YL/1)